# Random Number Generator with mt19937 Not Working Properly

Tags: c++, random, mt19937

The code is giving me the same number every time I run the program. I can't figure out why.

I looked up a tutorial on how to use the seed the generator properly, and for some reason my example won't work.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <random>

int returnRandomNumber(int to) {
    std::random_device rd;
    std::mt19937 mt(rd());
    std::uniform_int_distribution<> dist(0, to);

    return dist(mt);
}

int main() {

    int testNum;

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {

        testNum = returnRandomNumber(100);
        std::cout << testNum << "\n";

    }

}
```

Comment: `std::random_device` used to be broken in MinGW GCC (gave the same numbers every time). It was fixed in GCC 9.2. Update your compiler.

Comment: The random device, generator, and distribution must be re-used between iterations. Declare them at global scope or at least `static`.

Comment: Since the range of the distribution can change, it likely can't be static.

Comment: @sweenish You can change the range of an existing distribution.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat How?

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux `foo.param(std::uniform_int_distribution<>::param_type(x,y));` I think.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat I'm curious if this [resets](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/uniform_int_distribution/reset) the distribution. If `param_type` stores the full state of the distribution, then it would, and constructing a new instance would be equivalent. Otherwise, then that is an interesting approach.